# css increase bar width dynamically from left based on screen size

Tags: html, css

hi have bar to put breadcrum and some other content in middle and behind it there is background which is set from left to right.its full width from left
here is the image for this.[image]

```
<div class="yellow_bend">
    <div class="content_wrapper">
        <div class="category_links">
            <ul class="category_ul clearfix">
                <li class="first_li"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Tripping 

Canoes<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Sportsman Canoes<i class="fa 

fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Solo Canoes<i class="fa fa-

chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Racing Canoes<i class="fa 

fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="last_li"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Specialty 

Canoes<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- end category_ul -->
        </div>
        <!-- end category_links -->
    </div>
    <!-- end content_wrapper -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .yellow_bend {
     background:#e2aa12;
     position:absolute;
     left:0;
     min-height:32px;
     height:32px\9;
     min-width:300px;
     top:0
 }
 .yellow_bend:after {
     background:url(../images/cc_ylw_end.png) center right no-repeat;
     right:-35px;
     height:32px;
     width:50px;
     top:0;
     z-index:-1
 }
 .yellow_bend:before {
     background:#e2aa12;
     width:100%;
     height:32px
 }
 .category_ul li a {
     color:#1f1f1f;
     font-weight:500;
     font-size:12px;
     line-height:10px
 }
 .yellow_bend:after, .yellow_bend:before {
     position:absolute;
     content:''
 }
 .content_wrapper {
     width:960px;
     margin:0 auto;
     position:relative
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to play with before and after css properties if you want to extend only one side of html element across page something as below

HTML

```
<div id="page-wrap">
     <h2 class="left-only">To the left, to the left</h2>

    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#page-wrap {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
h1, h2, p {
    margin: 20px 0;
}
h2 {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 0;
    position: relative;
}
h2:before, h2:after {
    content:"";
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 9999px;
}
h2:before {
    right: 100%;
}
h2:after {
    left: 100%;
}
.left-only:after {
    display: none;
}
```

Useful js fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/LEesQ/

and this is the original article on CSS Tricks http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/

Hope this helps!